# How to draw many rectangles in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I have a picture, which counts numbers of pixels from two groups and computes them. It gives `P` in return for every sliding window. If `P` is greater than 6 it turns red but as it moves I don't get an image with red rectangles in places with `P > 6`. And that's what I want to achieve.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
I = imread('image');

imH = size(I, 1);
imW = size(I, 2);


windowWidth = 30;
windowHeight = 30;


step = 1;

for r = 1:step:imH - windowHeight + 1
    for c = 1:step:imW - windowWidth + 1


        Win = I(r:r + windowHeight - 1, c:c + windowWidth - 1, :);

        post = [c r windowHeight windowWidth];



        if P > 6
            subplot(121); imshow(I); title 'Image';
            hold on;      
            rectangle('Position', post, 'FaceColor', '(1 0 0)'); 

        end
end
```

How to draw the rectangle where `P` is greater than 6?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `pic`? I.e. what are you comparing to? Please add all the relevant pieces of code, and provide an example of the input and required input to show what you are trying to achieve more clearly. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my question.

Comment: The code is not complete. There are many undefined variables. The best help you will get if someone can copy-paste your code into MATLAB and see what you see. That requires all variables to be defined.

Comment: That said, your value of `pic` doesn’t change in the loop, it is computed once before the loop. You might want to compute it based on `W`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now I edited it well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does is to display the image and draw a rectangle over it every time a location is found. I imagine you end up with many images on top of each other, each one hiding the rectangles drawn earlier.

Instead, display the image once, then only draw the rectangle when you find a location. That is, move these lines out of the loop to the top of your code:

```
subplot(121); imshow(I); title 'Image';
hold on;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. But there is a problem. I need to use button click to draw rectangles, otherwise I get empty image.

Comment: @N.Cvala: I don’t see any interactive commands in your code. It should work on its own without the user clicking. I’m not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: Ok, yes, I'm sorry, my mistake, it works great! Thank you so much, you're the best!!